# Change a value (just a flag 0/1) depending on an entry in another table and - important - leave everything else unchanged

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to replace a taxonomy entry with a flag. The fields are kept in different tables. Here's what I did so far on db<>fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE `job_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `job_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);


INSERT INTO `job_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 1, '_remote_job', '0')
INSERT INTO `job_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (2, 2, '_remote_job', '0')
INSERT INTO `job_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (3, 3, '_remote_job', '0')
INSERT INTO `job_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (2, 3, '_something_else', 'ABCD')
INSERT INTO `job_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (4, 4, '_remote_job', '0')
INSERT INTO `job_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (2, 263, 0)
INSERT INTO `job_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (4, 263, 0)
INSERT INTO `job_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (1, 250, 0)
INSERT INTO `job_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (1, 263, 0)
INSERT INTO `job_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`, `term_order`) VALUES (2, 250, 0)
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM job_postmeta;
> ```
>
> ```
> meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value
> ------: | ------: | :-------------- | :---------
>       1 |       1 | _remote_job     | 0         
>       2 |       2 | _remote_job     | 0         
>       3 |       3 | _remote_job     | 0         
>       2 |       3 | _something_else | ABCD      
>       4 |       4 | _remote_job     | 0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  job_term_relationships;
> ```
>
> ```
> object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order
> --------: | ---------------: | ---------:
>         2 |              263 |          0
>         4 |              263 |          0
>         1 |              250 |          0
>         1 |              263 |          0
>         2 |              250 |          0
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE job_postmeta
>
> SET meta_value = 
> (
>   SELECT '1' 
>   FROM job_term_relationships
>   WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 263
>   AND object_id = meta_id
>
>   )
> WHERE meta_key = '_remote_job'
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM job_postmeta;
> ```
>
> ```
> meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value
> ------: | ------: | :-------------- | :---------
>       1 |       1 | _remote_job     | 1         
>       2 |       2 | _remote_job     | 1         
>       3 |       3 | _remote_job     | null      
>       2 |       3 | _something_else | ABCD      
>       4 |       4 | _remote_job     | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a83a52f0080f532ee84fd4d4e5b4e931)*

The only thing I didn't achive is keeping the '0' in _remote_job if there's no entry of '263' for the respectiv row. My first attempt set also _something_else to NULL. My attempts with a simple AND condition for meta_value = 0 or CASE to SET meta_value SELECT '0' failed.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can write proper `INNER JOIN UPDATE` clause, like :

```
UPDATE job_postmeta jp
INNER JOIN job_term_relationships jtr on jp.meta_id=jtr.object_id 
SET meta_value = '1' 
WHERE meta_key = '_remote_job'
and term_taxonomy_id = 263;
```

Result:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key       meta_value
1          1    _remote_job      1
2          2    _remote_job      1
3          3    _remote_job      0
2          3    _something_else  ABCD
4          4    _remote_job      1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4fc653b634229ce6a9d1c3bf51e09220

Comment: Thanks Ergest, as much as I can follow this on db<>fiddle, it doesn't work (for what ever reason) IRL. Instead of 529 entries, that should be found it gives "zero entries affected" 